# How to direct fputs to stdout in x86 on MacOS

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, x86-64, stdio

I cannot figure out how to call `fputs` from x86 in macOS and direct it to `stdout`, I think the problem is how to reference `stdout` as a file pointer to pass to `fputs`.  However, I am able to get `fputs` to work when I call it from Linux.

Here is the x86 code which works for Linux:

```
extern fputs
extern stdout

section .data
    text: db `hello, world\n`, 0

section .text
global main
main:
    lea rdi, QWORD [rel text]
    mov rsi, [stdout]
    call fputs
    
    ret
```

For macos/Macho64, my first attempt was:

```
extern _fputs
extern _stdout

section .data
    text: db `hello, world\n`, 0

section .text
global main
main:
    lea rdi, QWORD [rel text]
    mov rsi, [_stdout]
    call _fputs
    
    ret
```

But when linking, I am told that there is no symbol for `_stdout` nor is there a symbol for `stdout`.  And I cannot find any reference online explaining the proper way to call `fputs` from x86 on macOS and print to stdout

I have found explanations for how to call `fprintf` but for printing to a file not `stdout`. I tried simply passing `1` as the value for `stdout`, but that failed to work.

Comment: fprintf takes a `FILE*`, not a unix file descriptor (`int`), so `1` definitely will not work.  It would try to dereference `(FILE*)1` as a pointer, and of course segfault.  I don't know how MacOS normally defines `FILE *stdout`, but you could try looking at compiler output from clang (`clang -S hello.c`).

Comment: Also BTW, `QWORD [...]` is irrelevant for LEA: it has no size, just write `lea rdi, [rel text]` or `default rel` / `lea rdi, [text]`.

Comment: Compile a C program referencing `stdout` and inspect the assembly output (use `-S` to obtain it).  Replicate what the C compiler does.  I suppose it works like on FreeBSD where the identifier is really `__stdoutp` and thus you need to load from `___stdoutp` to obtain the right pointer.